# Rails 3: Expiring cached public/index.html page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following line on my **routes.rb** file.

```
root :to => "portfolio#index"
```

I cached the index page as follow:

```
class PortfolioController < ApplicationController
  caches_page :index

  def index
    @portfolio = Portfolio.where("featured = ? AND enabled = ?", false, true)
  end
end
```

And the **PortfolioSweeper.rb**

```
class PortfolioSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Portfolio

  def after_save(portfolio)
    expire_cache(portfolio)
  end

  def after_destroy(portfolio)
    expire_cache(portfolio)
  end

  private

    def expire_cache(portfolio)
      expire_page :controller => 'portfolio', :action => 'index'
    end

end
```

What is happening is that the `expire_page` only removes the **/public/portfolio.html** page but NOT **/public/index.html** page. Can you guys think of a way to remove both files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just passing it the path, like:

```
expire_page '/index.html'
```

Comment: Thanks Callmeed! It worked, just had to tweak it `expire_page '/index.html'`

Comment: Oh, yeah sorry ... the '/public' part isn't necessary. My bad.